# os.listdir only showing hidden file?

Tags: python

Honestly I have no idea what happened because one second this was working as it should and I was testing and made an unrelated change and now it is not. When I run it it only shows a file called '.vs' and none of the actual files in the directory? It is throwing an error saying I don't have permission. The directory looks fine in the variable explorer.. it never changes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
import urllib
import os


directory = r'C:/users/'
print(directory)

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: Are you sure that there are other files in that directory? And that you have permission to see them?

Comment: Yeah I didn't even change the directory and it was working as intended before... No matter what directory I pick it only pulls the .vs file then throws me an error.

Comment: I pasted same code, works fine for me. I guess it's permission issue. try creating folder with-in the code using ```os.mkdir("test_dir")``` before listing them, it will be created with default current user permissions, if test_dir shows up, then it's definitely permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, go to explorer and right click on the directory then select properties. In the properties window select Security tab. The Security window will show groups or user names that have permissions to access the directory and what they are allowed to do. If you do not have access click on Edit then click on Add. You can add
Everyone and give full control in permissions. This should allow full access to the directory. Not a good thing to do security wise but at least it should allow access.